# Trying to get Client ID and Client Secret for Yahoo API but no option to select "Installed Application"

Tags: yahoo

I've been attempting to utilize the Yahoo API to connect to fantasy sports data.  I don't have a web URL to connect to when I attempt to create an app, and everything I've read has mentioned that I should select "Installed Application" to avoid using a URL.
This option is not available to me.

[image: Yahoo Developer Screenshot]

On the official documentation this is what I see here

[image: Yahoo Developer Documentation]

Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm based out of Canada.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find the documentation for it, but what you want is called `oob` (out of bounds, out of band).  To get this to work, the steps are a little different (there is no such thing as installed application from what I'm aware of):

- Add `oob` as one of the redirect uris
- Make your normal request to the `auth/login`  uri
- This will give you a new page that provides you with a token.  At this point, you need to manually use this token when you request the `/auth/token` uri

This last step just replaces the redirect to `https://your-redirect.com/token` and you will end up in the same position as before.

Now, you still shouldn't put your `client_secret` in your application if you plan on releasing it, but if you're using it internally or letting others provide their own secret then you should be good.

If you find the original documentation with the PHP source code, you can follow this flow.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please refer to below link https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/
and click create app . you will find app key at the top
after successful creation.

Installed application is changed to public client.   [image]